# how to apply layout style to an apple news document using Chapter three php API

Tags: php, apple-news

I am using [AppleNewsAPI](https://github.com/chapter-three/AppleNewsAPI) to create apple news documents and submit them to apple news. Even looking at the API doc I can't understand how to grammatically apply the style. this is what I have done so far:

```
$obj = new Document(uniqid(), 'my headline', 'en', new Layout(7, 1024));
$obj->addComponent(new Body('article body'))
->addComponent(new Document\Components\Title('my headline'))
->addComponent(new Document\Components\Caption('my caption'))
[...]
->addComponentTextStyle('default', new ComponentTextStyle());
```

and this produce a valid json file for apple. How can I pass some style information using this library?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how you add styles and layouts:

```
$title_id = uniqid();
$title = new ChapterThree\AppleNewsAPI\Document\Components\Title( 'Your title', $title_id );

// Component style (Text)
$text_style = new ChapterThree\AppleNewsAPI\Document\Styles\ComponentTextStyle();
$text_style->setTextAlignment( 'left' );
$text_style->setTextTransform( 'none' );
$text_style->setFontName( 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold' );
$text_style->setLineHeight( 52 );
$text_style->setFontSize( 48 );
$text_style->setTextColor( '#000000' );

// Layout
$layout = new ChapterThree\AppleNewsAPI\Document\Layouts\ComponentLayout;();
$layout->setMargin( new ChapterThree\AppleNewsAPI\Document\Margin( 8, 5 ) );
$title->setTextStyle( $title_id . '-style' );
$title->setLayout( $title_id . '-layout' );
$document->addComponentTextStyle( $title_id . '-style', $text_style );
$document->addComponentLayout( $title_id . '-layout', $layout );

// Add to the main document object.
$document->addComponent($title);
```

Hope this helps.